# Data passing between view controllers not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Property in my AppDelegate.h: `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *bmiShared;`.
*(It is synthesized in my `AppDelegate.m`.)*

I have `AppDelegate.h` imported in both View Controller header files. I also have `AppDelegate *appDelegate` in each header.

In both implementation files *(`ViewController.m` and `TipsViewController.m`)* I have:

```
appDelegate.bmiShared = bmiView.text;
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong when passing the data over. I want the `floatValue` of `bmiView.text` to be available for use in my `TipsViewController` so that if the `floatValue` of `bmiView.text` is a certain amount, it will show the correct information in my `TipsViewController view`. I am using Storyboards if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second question today that you've asked on the same subject, and most of what you're doing is not right. To pass data between controllers, you shouldn't use the app delegate, and you shouldn't use a singleton. What you need to do is go back to the basics and try to understand what you're doing. Passing data between two controllers is a simple 3 step process:

1. Create a property in your "passing to" view controller to hold the data.
2. Get a reference to the "passing to" controller that you have or will have on screen.
3. Set the value of that property you created with data from your "passing from" controller.

The step that messes most newbies up is #2. You can't just alloc init an instance of the "passing to" controller, you need to get a reference to the one you created, usually in a xib or storyboard. How exactly to do that depends on how those two controllers relate to each other. Does one create an instance of the other and then push or present it? Is that "passing to" controller created in a xib, a storyboard, or in code? Are the controllers embedded in a navigation controller or tab bar controller? Are you moving to the second controller in code or directly with segues? These are the questions you need to think about, and understand how to answer, so you can get it right with any setup that you have.

If you can explain you controller setup (how the two relate to each other, and where you made them) I can point you to a more specific answer for step 2.

**After Edit:**

When you move between views with segues, the place you pass data is in prepareForSegue. The TipsViewController will be the segue.destinationViewController, so you do it like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
        TipsViewController *tipsVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        tipsVC.bmi = self.bmi;
    }
}
```

This example assumes you have created a property in TipsViewController called bmi, and that you have one called that in ViewController as well. This is all covered in Apple's "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" -- you should study it.

Comment: 1.) I am moving directly with segues.
2.) They are single view controllers.
3.) This is how the two relate to each other. The first view controller (ViewController) calculates the user's BMI then displays it in a label. For more information on the user's result, the user can press a button to go to the next view controller (TipsViewController). TipsViewController will show information based on the user's result, which I can't seem to pass on over. Certain BMI's call for certain objects to show on the TipsViewController. I need the final BMI to be shared amongst the views.

Comment: Ok I put the code you provided in my ViewController.m and created 2 properties. My question is, what do I connect the property in the TipsViewController too if I do not have a label present in the view? Also, I am getting a lot of errors because my label from ViewController (bmiView.text) isn't available in TipsViewController. Here's a piece of the code: 

`if ([**bmiView.text** floatValue] < 16.00) {
        classification.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bmi__0009_SEVTHIN.png"];
        severeThin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bmi__0011_MARKER"];`

Comment: @LoganLarroque, What do you connect the property to? I have no idea, what do you want to do with that information? I don't know what you mean by "my label from ViewController (bmiView.text) isn't available in TipsViewController" -- you should be passing the text to a string property you created in TipsViewController. Isn't bmiView.text a string?

Comment: I connected the property in ViewController to the BMI's label. The only string I have in my project is `bmiView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.02f", f*703];` which is the final result after all of the float calculations, and this string is in ViewController. I do not have any strings in TipsViewController. How would I create one?

Comment: @LoganLarroque, did you not understands what I put in my edit? You create a property in TipViewController: "@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *bmi;". Then in prepareForSegue, tipsVC.bmi = bmiView.text;

Comment: I still get "Use of undeclared identifier 'bmiView'" in the code that I sent you above (`if ([**bmiView.text** floatValue] < 16.00) { classification.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bmi__0009_SEVTHIN.png"]; severeThin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bmi__0011_MARKER"];`)

Comment: Do you have a property in ViewController called bmiView? How have you declared it? Did you synthesize it, or are you relying on the automatic synthesis?

Comment: I have the property `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *bmi;` in my ViewController like you said to put in both header files and they are both synthesized. Would you like to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: We can't move to a chat because you don't have enough points.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there anything else I can do to fix my problem? Remember if anything I have a link to download my project: (updated) http://www.mediafire.com/?m5zyj9xwkj03zhr

Comment: I used bmi as an example, but you say you have a bmiView in ViewController, and your string is bmiView.text. So, you should be able to do it like I said in my last comment. You didn't answer my question -- do you have a property called bmiView in Viewcontroller?

Comment: @LoganLarroque, I looked at your code, you have a property called bmiView in ViewController, but you're trying to use it in TipsViewController which doesn't have that property. You should replace all those references to bmiView.text in TipsViewController to just bmi -- that's the string property you passed the string (bmiView.text) to from ViewController.

Comment: By the way, your storyboard has a problem -- you shouldn't go backwards (from TipsViewController to ViewController) with a segue (except an unwind segue) because that will create a new instance of ViewController, it's not really going back at all. If you then go forward to TipsViewController again, that creates another one of those too, and you'll just keep piling up more and more instances of those two controllers. So, either do an unwind segue, or just dismiss TipsViewController.

Comment: @LoganLarroque, that's not really a good name -- you shouldn't call something a view if it's a string, but whatever. It's late here, so I'm off for the night.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything! My hunt to fix the problem has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, one possibility is that you are attempting to assign a value to `appDelegate.bmiShared` before `appDelegate` has been assigned a value (i.e. it's nil). Try swapping those two lines so you have

```
self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.appDelegate.bmiShared = bmiView.text;
```

There are a number of other things that could be going wrong, but without seeing all of your code, this seems like the most likely explanation.

Comment: I've provided a link to download my project if you want to see the rest of the code: http://www.mediafire.com/?9ewpz0uljf4hehv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data across view controllers you should look into using a singleton.

```
Singleton.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bmiShared;
+(Singleton *)sharedStore;

#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

+(Singleton *)sharedStore
{
    static Singleton *sharedStore = nil;

    if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }

    return sharedStore;
 }

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _bmiShared = [[NSString alloc] init];
}

    return self;
}
@end
```

That should work. When you want to set the string, import the singleton, alloc/init it, then set the bmiShared property like you would any other property. Do the same for the accessor on the view you want to see it on.

Comment: so I would have to add new Objective-C Class files under NSObject? I really have no clue how to implement a singleton. Just like I gave to the other person who responded to my question, here's a download link: http://www.mediafire.com/?9ewpz0uljf4hehv.

Comment: Yes, create a new class as a subclass of NSOBject, and implement it as above.

Comment: Ok, I put the above in Singleton.m (right?). If I'm right, does anything go in the .h?